# IOS received memory warning

Tags: ios

why am I received memory warning right after prefs synchronize? Thanks.

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSLog(@"Did Log In");
    NSLog(@"Access Token is %@", shared.accessToken );
    NSLog(@"Expiration Date is %@", shared.expirationDate );

    NSString *accessToken = shared.accessToken;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSString *expirationDate =[dateFormatter stringFromDate:shared.expirationDate ];

    **NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setObject:accessToken forKey:@"facebook-accessToken"];
    [prefs setObject:expirationDate forKey:@"facebook-expirationDate"];
    [prefs synchronize];**

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FBDidLoginCalled" object:nil];
}
```

Comment: What is the warning telling you? Are you using ARC?

Comment: Is it a system memory warning when you are executing the code? There may be a lot of reasons why memory warnings appear, like a too deep view controller stack or any other memory wasting actions.